Sass cannot find stylesheet to import
I am trying to setup a WordPress theme and am using JointsWP and SASS. When compiling using Prepros I get this error:
Can't find stylesheet to import.
@import '../../vendor/foundation-sites/scss/util/util';

I am calling the above @import from _settings.scss. This is my heirachy:
assets
- styles
-- scss
--- _settings.scss
- vendor
-- foundation-sites
--- scss
---- util
----- _util.scss

Any ideas what I am doing incorrectly please?
Thanks
